# Comparing sums and sums of products

Tags: number-theory

Suppose that $\sum_{i=1}^m c_i < \sum_{i=1}^m c_i'$ and $\sum_{i=1}^m d_i < \sum_{i=1}^m d_i'$.

Is it then true that $\sum_{i=1}^m c_i d_i < \sum_{i=1}^m c_i' d_i'$?

If not, is it true if $c_i, d_i, c_i', d_i' \geq 0$ for all $i$?

Comment: $1+10\lt3+9$; $1+10\lt3+9$; $(1)(1)+(10)(10)\gt(3)(3)+(9)(9)$.

Comment: Also posted to (and closed at) MO, without informing either site of the post at the other.

Answer (score 1):

Without the condition it fails for $m=1,c_1=-2,c'_1=-1,d_1=-2,d'_1=-1$.

Even with the condition it can fail for $m>1$ as in Gerry's example (posted as I was typing).

Comment: I recommend a speed-typing course.